# check database connect in symfony controller

Tags: symfony, pdo, doctrine

I build some kind CMS, where I can change parameters (parameters.yml) from my admin panel. User (admin) will be able to change database connections (name, host etc.). But I need to handle errors after that and let him rollback or something like that.

What I need:
- make connection to database after parameters change
- check if exists, etc..

What I can do:
- make new instance of \PDO and try / catch etc.

What I prefer:
- some kind symfony/doctrine help for that.

Is there something I can to instead new PDO? OR meyby my thinkinh way is wrong? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Doctrine DBAL Connection factory for that. In your controller (or service) you can get the "doctrine.dbal.connection_factory" service from container and create a new connection with the new parameters:

https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle/blob/master/ConnectionFactory.php#L51

and then try to connect with it:

https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php#L350

Here you can catch the errors that may occur.

Hope it helps